# javascript adding new elements with progressive IDs and updating the existing ones

Tags: javascript, createelement

I have already 3 existing boxes on a page (divs) with a unique ID (1,2,3) each. I want to have a button by each one of them that allows the user to add new boxes right below. These boxes should follow the already existing numbering. However, doing this will also imply to update the IDs of the already existing boxes underneath the new ones so the numbers match.

This is my code:

```
   function add_box(n) {
    document.getElementById("box"+(n<)).setAttribute("id", "box");
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.id="box"+(n+1);
    var txt = document.createTextNode("A new box");
    div.appendChild(txt);

    var newbox = document.getElementById("box"+n);
    insertAfter(div,newbox);
   }
```

HTML

```
<div id="box1">Whatever</div><input type="button" onclick="add_box(1)">
<div id="box2">Whatever</div><input type="button" onclick="add_box(2)">
<div id="box3">Whatever</div><input type="button" onclick="add_box(3)">
```

Its obviously not working because i guess i need to have an array with all the elements that contain "box" in the  ID and then somehow update their numbers but i dont know how to do all that.

Thank you.

Comment: Don't post code which generates console errors. Check your console. Then fix your syntax. If you are still stumped, **THEN** you can post. If by any chance you do not know how to view the console, then figure that out right away before you do anything else. By the way, why are you resetting the id on existing elements?

Comment: What does `"box"+(n<)` evaluate to? Where is the *insertAfter* function defined?

Comment: @torazaburo—because it inserts new divs between the existing divs (or is supposed to).

Comment: I just want to explain what im trying to do and the way i figured out a code which wont work. the inserAfter function works the same as insertBefore but does the opposite. I didnt include it to keep the sample as simple as possible.

Comment: If you insert a new div after *box1* and re–number the divs as suggested, then it will become *box2*, so the buttons will become disassociated with the div to which they originally applied. Perhaps you need to think of a better scheme?

Comment: I think that then everything will have to change but i cant think of another way. This is what i need.

Comment: I told you, i know the code is WRONG otherwise i would not being asking.

Answer (score 0):

The following does what you ask, but I suspect it isn't the result you want.

```
<script>

// Append a new div after one with id boxn
function add_box(n) {
  var el = document.getElementById('box' + n);
  var div = document.createElement('div');

  div.id = 'box' + ++n;
  div.appendChild(document.createTextNode('New box ' + n));
  el.parentNode.insertBefore(div, el.nextSibling);
  renumberDivs(div, n);
}

// Renumber all sibling divs after el
function renumberDivs(el, n) {

  // Note assignment, not equality
  while (el = el.nextSibling) {
    if (el.tagName && el.tagName.toLowerCase() == 'div'){
      el.id = 'box' + ++n;
    }
  }
}
</script>

<div id="box1">Whatever</div><input type="button" value="add below 1" onclick="add_box(1)">
<div id="box2">Whatever</div><input type="button" value="add below 2" onclick="add_box(2)">
<div id="box3">Whatever</div><input type="button" value="add below 3" onclick="add_box(3)">
```

Note that in the above, numbers are passed as arguments that are treated as numbers but also implicitly converted to strings when used for the ID value. That sort of type conversion isn't really liked, consider using a more explicit method.

After a few clicks, you may end up with something like:

```
<div id="box1">Whatever</div>
<div id="box2">New box 2</div>
<div id="box3">New box 3</div>
<div id="box4">New box 4</div>
<div id="box5">New box 4</div>
<div id="box6">New box 4</div>
<div id="box7">New box 2</div><input type="button" value="add a box" onclick="add_box(1)">
<div id="box8">Whatever</div><input type="button" value="add a box" onclick="add_box(2)">
<div id="box9">Whatever</div><input type="button" value="add a box" onclick="add_box(3)">
```

Comment: so far its working. Let me test it out further and i let you know. Thank you.

Comment: Okay, the problem i found now is that as you said, the buttons for the other boxes now are disassociated because they changed IDs but i think this could be easily solved by using a variable in onclick="add_box(this.id). What you think?